# Bizarre jQuery AJAX issue in IE7 and IE8 only - click after successful load fills page with 'undefined variable' errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, codeigniter

I have a page with a form that has multiple input fields that are dynamically filled based on a choice made on a dropdown selector.

```
$('#name').change(function() {

    var id = $('#name').val();

    var options = { 
        url:            'data/' + id,
        type:           'post',
        target:         '#insert',
        replaceTarget:  true,
        resetForm:      true
    }; 

    $('#name_form').ajaxSubmit(options);
});
```

On IE7 and IE8 I initially select a name from the dropdown.

The input fields are populated correctly based on the name I choose.

But if I click anywhere on the page, those same fields are then filled with 'undefined variable' errors output by my framework ( codeigniter ).

It's like the click sends an empty request that gets an empty response which will obviously crash the page since it has nothing to populate the input fields.

Needless to say this does not happen on FF, Cr, Saf - only IE.

Has anyone seen this behavior or have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Seems odd - have you tried building a test page that _only_ contains the form, jQuery, and that event listener? Just to narrow it down, I mean

Comment: good idea Flambino - well it looks like the culprit is `resetForm: true` -- when I remove that line things get back to normal -- perhaps I should use `val()` to reset the form instead

Comment: it also looks like both `resetForm` and `val()` put the focus on the dropdown, so any action (click) afterwards sends a new request for the first element of the dropdown, which is name='Select' value='' -- any idea how to get the focus out of there?

Comment: Well, calling `blur()` on a DOM element should remove its focus. But I can't see `val()` causing trouble (that `resetForm` causes problem makes sense, though). However, it might be easier to have your server send back JSON with the field names and values for the selected dropdown item, instead of replacing the entire form. Then you can go through the JSON obj and set the various fields to the correct values without the need of `resetForm`

Comment: another option I thought of and works well is to put a conditional to only do form submission `if $('#name').val() !== ''`

Comment: Oh yeah, absolutely do that; the user might pick the "blank", value in the dropdown purely by accident, and in that case it shouldn't do anything either. Didn't notice that such a check wasn't already in your code, or I would have suggested it too